# removeChild() deletes subelements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I got a challenge trying to better understand how things work in this world. There are two html pages:

**one.html**

```
<html>
<script>
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    var c = document.head;
    ifrm.src = 'two.html';
    (c = document.head || document.body) && c.appendChild(ifrm);
    //ifrm.parentNode && ifrm.parentNode.removeChild(ifrm)
</script>
</html>
```

**two.html**

```
<html>
<script>
    var newL = parent.document.createElement("img");
    newL.src = 'http://qwerty.com';
    parent.document.body.appendChild(newL);
</script>
</html>
```

I can control contents of two.html and I'm trying to create something in a parent, which would persist even after uncommenting the last line in the JS from one.html. As of now, the  tag is successfully created but once I uncomment the line with removeChild(), it's gone. Can one explain me why, and if there is a way to complete the task under specified circumstances? Thanks in advance!

Comment: not really :( updated description so it reflects the current state

Comment: no <body> in both script? check it

Comment: Can't say for certain, but I imagine it's because you are removing the iframe **immediately** and it has not loaded (and thus it's script that appends the `img` element hasn't executed). if you wait to remove `ifrm` until after it has fired a `load` event, I imagine the `img` element will have been appended.

Comment: @Adam yes i agree, i suggest , you catch event by document.onload then removeChild being exec

Comment: Try `setTimeout( function ( ) { ifrm.parentNode.removeChild(ifrm); }, 0 );`

Comment: Thanks for your responses! So if I control only two.html and one.html has to be as it is, there's no possibility to pause / create anything in parent from the newly created frame?

Comment: @c0rdis - that's correct. If you cannot change the fact that the iframe is removed from the DOM immediately after it is appended, then it's never loaded so it doesn't matter what you put in `two.html` if it never gets loaded.